# PhoneGap in Ubuntu

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu, phonegap-build

I'm in `ubuntu` 15.04 and trying to make `phonegap` and cordova works. I followed many tutorials and the most complete is [this](http://www.levibotelho.com/development/the-complete-guide-to-running-phonegap-on-ubuntu/)

I did everything but when I try run the "android" command I get "android: command not found". I don't know what to do... Some help?

obs1.: I have installed everything what you can think. I have Android Studio working very well in my computer, this means I have almost all pre-requisites of PhoneGap/Cordova

obs2.: I can run commands like 'cordova/phonegap create "directory" "package" "application"'.

obs3.: When the tutorial says "log out, and log back in", does this mean that I need to run "exit" twice (I'm running as super user) and `ctrl+alt+T` again? Or does this mean I need to log out my ubuntu's user? Since I didn't know what to do exactly, I run "reboot" command in terminal.

Thanks so much

Comment: You need to put the tools/platform-tools folders of android sdk to your path.

Comment: @Enrique, your are using Cordova/Phonegap SDK for IDE. The blog you point to is using the CLI, The blog post is fair - at best. *Phonegap Build* is for Adobe's cloud based build service. It is not related to your question - in any way. READ THIS: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: READ [Top Bloggers for Phonegap](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/documentation/phonegap/bookmarks/topBloggers.html)

Comment: FWIW: I use Ubuntu 14.04 and use *Phonegap Build* I do not compile locally.

Comment: @Enrique-René, is your issue solved?

Comment: I did a link (ln) and it solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you do step 7 in the guide you have linked I believe you need to change the path the author has supplied.

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS"
```

For my installation of Cordova on UBUNTU machine running 15.10 (did last week 19/11/15) the path to the tools and platform tools directory is different from this(The folder structure when you install the SDK is different even when I extract the package to /usr/local/android-sdk-linux as the guide says). Ensure that this is the correct path on your machine and if not change accordingly.

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

And edit for correct paths.After edits have been made you will need to log in and out for changes to take place.

Comment: I did it, but didn't work... Now I used ln command and create a link.